# configure warns that installed libraries are missing

Tags: linux, configure, xscreensaver

I hope this is an appropriate forum for this question. I'm trying to learn the "`configure, make, make install`" workflow that seems to be well-known Linux convention. I am trying to apply this to xscreensaver. In addition to reading the xscreensaver website, and googling around this topic, I'm unable to find the workaround to this: Having downloaded and unzipped xscreensaver, I run `configure`. It outputs the following warnings:

```
Warning: The GTK libraries do not seem to be available; the
         `xscreensaver-demo' program requires them.

Warning: The GDK-Pixbuf library was not found.

Warning: The XPM library was not found.
```

In order to understand the "`configure, make, make install`", I wanted to work through these warnings until `configure` completes cleanly.

As far as I can tell, I have the GDK-Pixbuf library:

```
>sudo dnf install gdk-pixbuf2
Package gdk-pixbuf2-2.30.3-1.fc20.x86_64 is already installed, skipping.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
>
>find /usr/local/lib -name "*pixbuf*"
/usr/local/lib/libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/gdk-pixbuf-2.0.pc
/usr/local/lib/libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.la
/usr/local/lib/libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0.2800.2
/usr/local/lib/libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so
>
>echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib64
```

(I created LD_LIBRARY_PATH as part of my aimless debugging this problem).

Can anyone advise how to further debug this? Why might `configure` complain about a missing pixbuf library, when it seems to be present? Even though this question is specific to xscreensaver, I'd like to learn the workflow of how experienced Linux users work through figuring out how to install dependencies to pacify `configure`.

**Update**:

My Linux distro:

```
>cat /proc/version 
Linux version 3.11.10-301.fc20.x86_64 (mockbuild@bkernel01.phx2.fedoraproject.org) (gcc version 4.8.2 20131017 (Red Hat 4.8.2-1) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Thu Dec 5 14:01:17 UTC 2013
```

Comment: some distributions split libraries into multiple packages.  while `gdk-pixbuf2` may provide the library itself, you may also need `gdk-pixbuf2-devel` for associated header files in order to compile other software with it.  (debian-based distributions use `-dev` packages for the same purpose.)  if that's not enough info to help you find your solution, please update your question to include what distribution you're using.

Comment: Check for 32 bit vs 64 bit. Also see what's in config.log. That may have some clues.  Also, did you tell it to look in /usr/local?  It won't look there unless you tell it.

Comment: @quixotic edit: he has it installed in /usr/local, probably not an RPM install.

Comment: @quixotic - Updated post with my linux distro.

Comment: @quixotic - I think you were right to suggest installing gdk-pixbuf2-devel. After doing so, and re-running `configure`, the warnings for GDK-Pixbuf and XPM went away. If you post as an answer, I would accept it. Could you explain a bit more about this also? This looks like another Linux convention that I should be aware of. When you are confronted with a situation where you need to install required libs/headers/software in general, how do you know what package(s) to install with dnf? I feel like there's tribal knowledge about all this that I've yet to learn.

Comment: @StoneThrow `dnf` is your package manager, so i assumed you are using Fedora or a Fedora-based distribution.  (Debian-based distribos use `apt`, Arch-based use `pacman`, and others might use one of these 3 or provide their own.)  your distribution's documentation likely refers to the need for `-devel` or `-dev` packages for compiling your own software; most distributions provide web-based package search tools to help determine which ones.  i consulted [Fedora's](https://admin.fedoraproject.org/pkgdb/) to find the GDK `-devel` package.