# How to satisfy configure dependencies?

Tags: linux, gtk, configure, dnf

This question is related to my other question [configure warns that installed libraries are missing](https://superuser.com/questions/1181457/configure-warns-that-installed-libraries-are-missing) . That question was specific to `xscreensaver`, but this is a more generic question RE: `configure` using `gtk` as an example. I am having trouble trying to install `gtk` as one of the dependencies I'd like to satisfy for `xscreensaver`; please see the logs below:

```
>curl -LSso gtk+-2.24.31.tar.xz http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/gnome/sources/gtk+/2.24/gtk+-2.24.31.tar.xz                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
>tar xf gtk+-2.24.31.tar.xz 
>cd gtk+-2.24.31/
>./configure
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /usr/bin/mkdir -p
...
configure: error: Package requirements (glib-2.0 >= 2.28.0    atk >= 1.29.2    pango >= 1.20    cairo >= 1.6    gdk-pixbuf-2.0 >= 2.21.0) were not met:

No package 'atk' found
No package 'pango' found
No package 'cairo' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables BASE_DEPENDENCIES_CFLAGS
and BASE_DEPENDENCIES_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
>sudo dnf install atk
[sudo] password for user: 
Package atk-2.10.0-1.fc20.x86_64 is already installed, skipping.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
>sudo dnf install pango
Package pango-1.36.1-3.fc20.x86_64 is already installed, skipping.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
>sudo dnf install cairo
Package cairo-1.14.0-2.fc20.x86_64 is already installed, skipping.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
```

**Question**:

I'm confused by this process of compiling/installing software on Linux. It looks to me like `gtk`'s configuration process cannot find the `atk`, `pango`, and `cairo` packages, but the `dnf` package installer claims they are installed. What is it that indicates to a given piece of software whether a dependency is present or not? How do you reconcile conflicting claims like this whether a required software is installed or not? Thanks for guidance.

Comment: " but the dnf package installer claims they are installed. " - To what directory?  What specific versions of those dependencies are required by that specific version of gtk++ your trying to install?

Comment: @Ramhound - how do I get the answers to your questions? I only make my claim based on the output of `dnf install atk`, etc. which says they are installed, but does not say what directory...?

Comment: The package you attempted to install requires cairo >= 1.6 you have 1.14.0-2.fc20 installed.

Comment: @Ramhound - I see a line in `config.log` that implies it's looking for `atk >= 1.29.1`, `pango >= 1.2.0`, and `cairo >= 1.6`. So `atk` and `pango` versions should be satisfactory, no?

Comment: You might have them installed but, none of those packages, were discovered.  You have at least one package that isn't the correct version.

Comment: @Ramhound - I've tried `dnf upgrade cairo`, `dnf check-update cairo`, and `dnf info cairo` and they all indicate there is no newer version of cairo that can be installed. I wonder: is this dependent on the Linux distro? I assume there must exist version >= 1.6 because gtk+ is looking for it...so why does `dnf` not find it?

Comment: "You might have them installed but, none of those packages, were discovered" - what is the mechanism that makes `configure` "aware" of installed packages? This is part of what I'm trying to learn.